# How to get elements of next page after changing pages with a javascript command?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

`driver.execute_script("paginateGayrimenkul(2);")`
this code should be taking the webdriver to the second page of the website. But when I search for elements I still get the elements of page one

The paginateGayrimenkul(2); command works on chrome's console so I know that's not the issue

My question is: How can I get the elements of the new page my code should be directing to?

Things I tried but didn't work:

```
newURl = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to.window(newURl)
```

Comment: Did you try refreshing once you are on second page ? and then grab them

Comment: I did, it's the same results

Comment: Can you share URL ?

Comment: https://isbank.intengo.com/gm-index.intengo?cid=754728

Comment: eve nfrom console it lands back in the same url

Comment: with just the cid changes , what is the expected result

Comment: doesn't sound like you need to switch driver handles here.   Use a webdriverwait along with expected condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply something like that:

```
current_url = driver.current_url # capture current page url
driver.execute_script("paginateGayrimenkul(2);") # calling the new url
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.url_changes(current_url)) # wait until you have been redirected to the new page
# here you can find the element you want in the new page
```